Facebook Conversion API - Same event but different event ids shown, how to solve it?
I am sending data using GA4 through Facebook conversion api. Now, when I visit a page, two "Page View" events are fired and shown in facebook test events, one from browser and one from server, but they don't have the same event id, so I can not deduplicate them now. Help needed.
I tried double checking but it didn't work.

"I tried" .. let's see it.
